# Amount of data in a database table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to run an alter query on a table, and its giving me a

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
MySQL server has gone away.
```

The query that I am running is

```
 alter table table_name modify column_name DOUBLE ( 16, 2) default 8.5;
```

I am guessing that the table contains a lot of data, and hence the alter is taking a lot of time, and the server connection is lost.

My query is,

Firstly,

How do I find out the amount of data present in the table ? ( in MB/GB i suppose).

Secondly, 
 In case the table does contain a huge amount of data, then how do I perform the alter on this table ?

Comment: You'd probably do better asking this on [dba.se]

Comment: You need to check the MySQL's error log. If you're executing the statement from some web frontend (like PHPMyAdmin), try to execute the statement directly from mysql cli (mysql).

Comment: If its innodb, try the Percona Tools for online table changes

Comment: I'd like to add that pt-online-schema-change is storage engine agnostic

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but in most cases a `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` column should be `DECIMAL` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the server's error log(s).  There are too many situations that could cause this problem.  For example:

- The table is corrupt, and InnoDB detects this while reading an invalid page checksum.  The default behavior here is to shutdown to force an administrator to intervene.
- Your server is over configured to use way too much memory.  The OOM killer terminates mysqld.
- There is no problem at all.  The client disconnects, but the server keeps running the ALTER statement, and it eventually finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Will give you the database size in MB.

Sorry, I can't help you with your second question.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, you can:

- Create a new table with the new column structure
- Copy the data from the old table into the new table `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`
- `DROP` the old table
- `RENAME TABLE` the new table to the old table name.